# How to render tag script in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to include the linkedin follow button in the specific location of my react page. How do I render the tags below into a div?

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: pt_BR</script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="xxxxx"></script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You wouldn't render script tags with react. Just append them to your html file.

Comment: Alternatively you could look at https://github.com/leozdgao/react-async-script-loader

Answer (score 0):

You can create a React component that renders script tags with the JavaScript code inserted as a string using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, like this:

```
function LinkedInSnippet({ id }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <script
                src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js"
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: 'lang: pt_BR'
                }}
            />
            <script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id={id} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

I assumed that you'd want to set the ID dynamically, so I've made so that it is passed to the component as a prop. You can then use the component like this:

```
<LinkedInSnippet id="xxxxxxx" />
```